# WPF binding is only applied after xaml hot reload modification

Tags: c#, binding, datagrid

I have a strange problem.
I am working on VS19, I have bindings and they only work when I made changes to the xaml file after launch ... I think the data grid content is not refreshed well but I do not do not know why.

Operations:

1. I execute the program.
2. In a datagrid user modify cell 1 binding to property A (twoway mode, on lostfocus because a converter must do its job first).
3. the lost focus event modify a property B based on property A (I check that value is well changed)
4. the cell 2 is bind to property B (twoway mode  on propertychange) but no change in datagrid...
5. I modify the xaml file (I can change something and revert this change again) the cell 2 has now property B

To check if value is well binding I've add a DataGridTextColumn. The value is only visible after I enter in edit mode of this cell.

So here some code :

the xaml :

```
                  <DataGrid x:Name="DT" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsEnabled="True" LostFocus="DT_LostFocus">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding StringPropertyA, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource dateChecker}}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MonthSimple" Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding StringPropertyB, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Month">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding StringPropertyB, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                               SelectedItem="{Binding StringPropertyB, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                           ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Combobox, Path=ItemsSource}" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}">
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>                           
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

the code behind :

```
        private void DT_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (CustomClass custom in DT.ItemsSource)
        {
            if ((custom.StringPropertyA == "" || custom.StringPropertyA == null) && DateTime.TryParse(custom.StringPropertyA , out DateTime date))
            {
                custom.StringPropertyB = OtherOperations(date);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone spot my mistakes? or tell me why the binding doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What does your `dateChecker` converter? Why do you have a string-property if you need DateTime? The logic in code-behind `DT_LostFocus` can be moved in the setter of `CustomClass.StringPropertyA`.

Comment: DateChecker convert string from several string input to a date in specific format. Per example : x/x/x is converted to dd/MM/yyyy, x is converted to the last day of the x month of this year or last year if is in futur. So it's a custom input.

Comment: actually the customClass is in use for other purpose but if it can help I can test with an new class with a setter

Comment: As @Steeeve suggested, I moved the lost focus logic to the setter. Thanks for your idea, this clarifies the code. But the same behavior is observed, the value behind is changed but the binding is not visible. For example, I always have to enter in celledit mode to get the new value.

Comment: I think I've found a workaround. I subscribe my class to `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire a `OnPropertyChanged("StringPropertyB");` in my `StringPropertyA` setter after I update its value. It'seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some changes that work for me. As @Steeeve suggested, I moved the logic to the setter:

So the XAML:

```
              <DataGrid x:Name="DT" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsEnabled="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding StringPropertyA, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource dateChecker}}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="MonthSimple" Width="Auto"  Binding="{Binding StringPropertyB, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Month">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding StringPropertyB, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                           SelectedItem="{Binding StringPropertyB, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Combobox, Path=ItemsSource}" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle1}">
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                           
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

the code behind :

```
public class CustomClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    public string StringPropertyA { get; set; }
    private string _stringPropertyB;
    public string StringPropertyB
    {
        get { return _stringPropertyB; }
        set
        {
            if ((this.StringPropertyA == "" || this.StringPropertyA == null) && DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime date))
            {
                this.StringPropertyB = OtherOperations(date);
                OnPropertyChanged();
                _stringPropertyB = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _stringPropertyB= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

The Binding is yet always up to date.
Thks @Steeeve for your suggestion!